# how to convert uploaded data table to data.frame code in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an excel data and I uploaded to R.

```
dataA=data.frame(read_excel("soybean_yield.xlsx", sheet=1))
dataA
   season    crop plot treatment grain_yield
1    2023 Soybean    1       tr1   32.198627
2    2023 Soybean    1       tr2    4.967028
3    2023 Soybean    1       tr3    4.263257
4    2023 Soybean    1       tr3    1.043018
5    2023 Soybean    1       tr5    8.663200
6    2023 Soybean    2       tr1   25.591932
7    2023 Soybean    2       tr2   35.680821
8    2023 Soybean    2       tr3   29.225748
9    2023 Soybean    2       tr3   39.878693
10   2023 Soybean    2       tr5   20.658753
11   2023 Soybean    3       tr1   15.522533
12   2023 Soybean    3       tr2   23.207927
13   2023 Soybean    3       tr3   44.555002
14   2023 Soybean    3       tr3   44.988903
15   2023 Soybean    3       tr5   32.371277
16   2023 Soybean    4       tr1   20.492676
17   2023 Soybean    4       tr2   35.178372
18   2023 Soybean    4       tr3   37.273636
19   2023 Soybean    4       tr3    9.622045
20   2023 Soybean    4       tr5   16.787561
21   2023 Soybean    5   control  103.185748
22   2023 Soybean    6   control   60.778144
23   2023 Soybean    7   control   32.957160
24   2023 Soybean    8   control   66.174361
```

Now, I want to convert this data table to `data.frame()` code to save the data as code.

I can use `dput(dataA)`, but I think there are other ways to convert to `data.frame()` code.

The below code is the format I want.

```
data.frame(season=rep(c(2023),24),
           crop=rep(c("soybean"),24),
           plot= c(rep(c(1,2,3,4),each=5),5,6,7,8),
           treatment= c(rep(c("tr1","tr2","tr3","tr4"),each=5), rep(c("control"),4)),           
           grain_yield=c(32.2,5.0,4.3,1.0,8.7,25.6,35.7,29.2,39.9,20.7,15.5,23.2,44.6,
           45.0,32.4, 20.5,35.2,37.3,9.6,16.8,103.2,60.8,33.0,66.2))
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The standard way to save R objects to files is the RDS file format, `saveRDS(dataA, file = "your_file.Rds")` (though other formats are more nicely human-readable and portable). The standard way to create copy/pasteable code to reproduce an object is `dput()`. Why do you want something else? What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: As a side-note, `read_excel()` returns a data frame. Wrapping `data.frame()` around it is not necessary.

Comment: @GregorThomas The reason I want to convert to data.frame() code is to save data as code (text). I used to lose my Excel data, so I want to save it as text and save it to my web note, and later want to use it directly. What I want is not to save another file such as .Rds, but simply save it as text. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, `dput()` works very well for that. Why not use `dput`?

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for your answer!! except dput(), are there any other ways to convert to data.frame() code?

Comment: Not that I know of. What don't you like about `dput`? I've asked this question in every comment, you seem to be avoiding it.

Comment: @GregorThomas I prefer the data.frame() format as it's more familiar, and that's the only reason. Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: I've added an answer suggesting the `constructive` package, which seems to achieve your goals better than `datapasta` or `dput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datapasta` package apparently has a function for this:

```
datapasta::df_paste(dataA)
# data.frame(
#   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
#                        season = c(2023,
#                                   2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,
#                                   2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,
#                                   2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023),
#                          crop = c("soybean",
#                                   "soybean","soybean","soybean","soybean",
#                                   "soybean","soybean","soybean","soybean",
#                                   "soybean","soybean","soybean","soybean",
#                                   "soybean","soybean","soybean","soybean",
#                                   "soybean","soybean","soybean","soybean",
#                                   "soybean","soybean","soybean"),
#                          plot = c(1,1,1,
#                                   1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,
#                                   4,5,6,7,8),
#                     treatment = c("tr1",
#                                   "tr1","tr1","tr1","tr1","tr2","tr2","tr2",
#                                   "tr2","tr2","tr3","tr3","tr3","tr3",
#                                   "tr3","tr4","tr4","tr4","tr4","tr4",
#                                   "control","control","control","control"),
#                   grain_yield = c(32.2,5,
#                                   4.3,1,8.7,25.6,35.7,29.2,39.9,20.7,
#                                   15.5,23.2,44.6,45,32.4,20.5,35.2,37.3,9.6,
#                                   16.8,103.2,60.8,33,66.2)
#            )
```

It's much less robust than `dput`. With a little testing, it seems to keep factors as factors, but doesn't preserve the order of the levels. It save `Date` class objects as strings, so I would certainly not trust it on any classes other than the most basic built-in classes. On the other hand, `dput()` will work for just about any R object.

Answer (score 2):

A great new option is the `constructive` package, which is similar to `dput()` and `datapasta` but with more idiomatic construction that looks very similar to how you created the data frame in the first place, and is typically shorter. In my testing the output preserves more of the class information (e.g. Dates, grouping) than `datapasta` does.

```
#https://cynkra.github.io/constructive/
#install.packages("constructive")
#remotes::install_github("cynkra/constructive") #[Alternative]
constructive::construct(dataA)
```

Result

```
data.frame(
  season = rep(2023, 24L),
  crop = rep("soybean", 24L),
  plot = rep(seq(1, 8, by = 1), rep(c(5L, 1L), each = 4L)),
  treatment = rep(c("tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr4", "control"), rep(5:4, c(4L, 1L))),
  grain_yield = c(
    32.2, 5, 4.3, 1, 8.7, 25.6, 35.7, 29.2, 39.9, 20.7, 15.5, 23.2, 44.6, 45,
    32.4, 20.5, 35.2, 37.3, 9.6, 16.8, 103.2, 60.8, 33, 66.2
  )
)
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed it even does the `rep()` code like OP was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want clean the *treatment* column for some reason. To do this you could extract the numbers using `sub` after replacing *control* first with some high value so it comes last in `order`.

```
> transform(dat, treatment=x[order(sub('\\D*', '', sub('control', 999, x)))])
   season    crop plot treatment grain_yield
1    2023 Soybean    1       tr1   32.198627
2    2023 Soybean    1       tr1    4.967028
3    2023 Soybean    1       tr1    4.263257
4    2023 Soybean    1       tr1    1.043018
5    2023 Soybean    1       tr2    8.663200
6    2023 Soybean    2       tr2   25.591932
7    2023 Soybean    2       tr2   35.680821
8    2023 Soybean    2       tr2   29.225748
9    2023 Soybean    2       tr3   39.878693
10   2023 Soybean    2       tr3   20.658753
11   2023 Soybean    3       tr3   15.522533
12   2023 Soybean    3       tr3   23.207927
13   2023 Soybean    3       tr3   44.555002
14   2023 Soybean    3       tr3   44.988903
15   2023 Soybean    3       tr3   32.371277
16   2023 Soybean    4       tr3   20.492676
17   2023 Soybean    4       tr5   35.178372
18   2023 Soybean    4       tr5   37.273636
19   2023 Soybean    4       tr5    9.622045
20   2023 Soybean    4       tr5   16.787561
21   2023 Soybean    5   control  103.185748
22   2023 Soybean    6   control   60.778144
23   2023 Soybean    7   control   32.957160
24   2023 Soybean    8   control   66.174361
```

### Edit

Not really sure what you want, you could `sink()` the output in a text file.

```
sink('foo.txt')  ## open sink
dat  ## print df
sink()  ## close sink, df is saved and looks exactly like console output
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(season = c(2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 
2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 
2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 
2023L), crop = c("Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", 
"Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", 
"Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", 
"Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", 
"Soybean", "Soybean"), plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L
), treatment = c("tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr3", "tr5", "tr1", "tr2", 
"tr3", "tr3", "tr5", "tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr3", "tr5", "tr1", 
"tr2", "tr3", "tr3", "tr5", "control", "control", "control", 
"control"), grain_yield = c(32.198627, 4.967028, 4.263257, 1.043018, 
8.6632, 25.591932, 35.680821, 29.225748, 39.878693, 20.658753, 
15.522533, 23.207927, 44.555002, 44.988903, 32.371277, 20.492676, 
35.178372, 37.273636, 9.622045, 16.787561, 103.185748, 60.778144, 
32.95716, 66.174361)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"
))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! except dput(), are there any other ways to convert to data.frame() code?

Comment: @Jin.w.Kim Have you tried `dat <- openxlsx::read.xlsx("foo.xlsx", sheet=1)`?

Comment: @jay.sf OP wants to save the data frame as R code, just like `dput()` does, but they don't like `dput()` for unspecified reasons. Their issue is not importing the data, their issue is finding a alternative to `dput` that is somehow different.

Comment: @GregorThomas Really? OK, OP could try `sink('foo.txt'); dat; sink()`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Gregor Thomas comments:

When `dataA` is your data frame:

#### using `dump()`

```
dump("dataA", file = "dataA.R")
```

#### using `deparse()`

```
deparse(dataA)
```